# The package version is too long

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

while publishing jar to the azure repository i'm getting error:

```
Could not PUT 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/****/_packaging/***/maven/v1/com/syncier/ms-vwb-keycloak-spring-boot-starter/0.8.0-renovate-org.keycloak-keycloak-admin-client-9.x-SNAPSHOT/ms-vwb-keycloak-spring-boot-starter-0.8.0-renovate-org.keycloak-keycloak-admin-client-9.x-20200719.222439-1.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request - The package version is too long
```

i read somewhere that the limit for version is 127, but jar filename is only 111 chars, do i calculate wrong?

Comment: You probably hit the max path length (255) on the server-side if it is hosted on a Windows server

Answer (score 1):

> i read somewhere that the limit for version is 127, but jar filename
> is only 111 chars, do i calculate wrong?

*Your representation will then be encoded such that the resulting string can be ordered against the other version strings, regardless of the length of each segment of the version string.*

So we do have a length limit of 127 characters, but that's for **final encoded string** instead of your **original string**.

I'm not sure about how the version string will be encoded behind, however you can check [one example](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/371079/view.html) from Product Team for more details:

Original string => `201810251128.develop.beta-306-ddd-62-beta-2655-cd-9-alpha-92319-e-41-baa-990-bd-883-f-31` (88 characters). Corresponding encoded string would be 216 characters.

So I think your string has extended the limit cause your original string has 111 characters, the corresponding encoded string must be larger than the limit. As a workaround I think you should simplify the version string so that the package can be published successfully.

Comment: that's the goal to shorten version string, i just need to know to which point :) will guess then

Comment: I can't find any document about how the string is encoded in the behind. So my suggestion is to shorten the string as short as possible~

Comment: @mazdack If my answer resolves your puzzle about why the 111 characters is larger than the limit, could you [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that more members can benefit from the useful info!